# Data Preprocessing in ggplot2

Tags: r, csv, plot, ggplot2

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93667882/issue_data.csv This is csv file i am working in R to plot stacked bar graph. By doing maunal entry of data in R i am able to do it. but i am having a hard time to per-process the csv file to make it suitable for ggplot2.

I want to plot three different stacked bar plotting  per BU, per country, per Division where each bar would be 100% of All and rest Critical, Error, Warning, Review should be stacked on top of another according to their contribution in the ALL.

NOTE: All=Critical+Error+Warning+Review.

Comment: See my comments below my answer to your other question. Show us somme effort. If you look at the answer below (that in fact is nearly the same than mine) and combine this answer with my answer to your other question, your problem should be fully solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to modify some factor levels. This is necessary since some levels include space (e.g., `"  CT "` should be identical to `"CT"`)

```
dat <- read.csv("issue_data.csv")
dat <- transform(dat, BU = gsub(" ", "", as.character(BU)),
                 Country = gsub(" ", "", as.character(Country)))
```

The following code creates a plot for `BU`. Aggregate the different variables along the levels of `BU`:

```
agg <- aggregate(cbind(Critical, Error, Warning, Review) ~ BU, dat, sum)
agg[-1] <- agg[-1] / rowSums(agg[-1]) # since you want bars of equal height
```

You can arrange your data frame easily with the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
dat2 <- melt(agg, id.vars = c("BU"), 
             measure.vars = c("Critical", "Error", "Warning", "Review"))
```

Now, the plot can be created.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat2) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = BU, y = value, fill = variable), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But i want in a percentile format in the Y Asis. How can it be done. I am new to R

Comment: @KoushikSaha Do you just want other labels for the y-axis?

Comment: No no bar should not be counts. it should be in percentage like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93667882/Plot1.png

Comment: @KoushikSaha See the update of my answer.